# ReactRouter's Hash Router not working on hash change

Tags: reactjs, webpack, react-router-v4

I'm using ReactRouter's `<HashRouter>` class (my server isn't configured for `<BrowserRouter>` and this is an internal tool so I don't care about search engines or etc).

I have precisely one route:

```
<Route path="/:datestring" component={ConnectedDatePage} />
```

On my development version, this all works perfectly. I then package the app up (using webpack) into a single page and publish it, and on the server, clicking links changes the hash—but there is no corresponding change on the page.

Reloading the page with the new hash renders everything correctly, but then changing the hash again does nothing. What might be going on here?

UPDATE: I suspect it may be because, on the server, it is not running at the root level (it's at, e.g., `http://example.com/app/#/20170203/` instead of `http://localhost/#/20170203/`). I don't know how to configure the router to handle this, though.

Comment: Would you be willing to share the Git repo? This is an interesting issue and I'd like to investigate, would help if I could run the app.

Comment: I don't think I can share the whole repo, unfortunately. Is there more information about the configuration I can share that would help?

Comment: What backend server do you have running? You're probably running webpack-dev-server locally that redirects all route changes to `index.html` automatically. You'll need the same kind of setup on the server the app gets deployed to.

Comment: It's just being served as static pages on a server. I'm not sure of the exact configuration, but in principle using a hash router obviates the need for server customization—any hash route will still point to the relevant `index.html`. (And, indeed, all the routes *do* work—it's just that the `hashchange` event doesn't engage the router. It is firing, though, I checked.)

Comment: Years old question, but facing same issue.

Answer (score 0):

My issue was I was not specifying `exact` option in the routes:

```
<Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
<Route exact path="/:datestring" component={ConnectedDatePage} />
```

Without this option, Home page was being rendered at all times. Very basic but fatal mistake. :D